# Ubuntu Freeradius logging to AWS

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I want logging for RADIUS authentication and accounting to Cloud Watch of Amazon, I've read the document on [freeradius document](https://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Logging) for logging, but seem no options for it.

Please help me, thanks.